# Efficiently merge partial files in C

Tags: c, file, pointers, fwrite

I have written a method that merges parts of a downloaded file into one file.

```c
void merge_files(char *src, char *dest, int bytes, int tasks) {
  FILE *write_to;
  FILE *read_from;
  char dest_local[256];
  char read[256];
  char c[bytes];
  remove_char(dest, "/", "-");
  sprintf(dest_local, "%s/%s", src, dest);
  write_to = fopen(dest_local, "w");

  for (int file_i = 0; file_i < tasks; file_i++) {
    sprintf(read, "%s/%d", src, file_i * bytes);
    read_from = fopen(read, "r");
    if (!(read_from))
      return;
    if ((file_i + 1) == tasks) {
      while (fread(&c, 1, 1, read_from) == 1) {
        fwrite(&c, 1, 1, write_to);
      }

    } else {

      while (fread(&c, bytes, 1, read_from) == 1) {
        fwrite(&c, bytes, 1, write_to);
      }
    }
    fclose(read_from);
    remove(read);
  }
  fclose(write_to);
}
```

We use `fwrite()` to write each complete file of `size(bytes)`, then on the final instance I use `fwrite()` for individual characters to stop 'over padding' of the file. i.e. empty space in an image file.

It also deletes these files. The partial files are named for their place in the file i.e.

0 - file containing bytes from zero to <bytes>

1024 -file containing bytes from 1024 to (1024 + <bytes>)

...

Until the final file which contains whatever the remainder is.

The files are packed into a file at src/dest.

I would like to make this code more efficient possibly using a concurrent queue or `fork()`.

Notably I'd like to implement it synchronously, but I'm not really sure how.

I'm also unsure as to how I can upload some of the partial files for testing; The above program outputs a file correctly containing the concatenated partial files.

Comment: Reading byte per byte does not look efficient at all to me. You should read/write chunks of say 64K or so.

Comment: Also, there's no real reason to handle the final file differently. Use `fread` to fill a buffer – it'll return the number of bytes it reads – and `fwrite` to write that many bytes into the output file.

Comment: Hi, Is this not what (while (fread(&c, bytes, 1, read_from) == 1)) is doing  ? Cheers

Comment: Also, any heavy-lifting on disk should use your platform-specific asynchronous IO APIs - using the CRT `fread` is fine for portable command-line programs, but really doesn't scale well.

Comment: Your code has `int bytes` but then passes that into `fread`, but `fread` wants `size_t size` - so your code may break on systems where `sizeof(int) != sizeof(size_t)` such as with a suitably configured x64 toolchain.

Comment: `write_to = fopen(dest_local, "w");` is going to cause all kinds of problems.  First, `"w"` mode will truncate the file to zero length each time you open it, wiping out all the previous data you may have written while merging files.  Second, `"w"` mode opens the file in *text* mode, which on some OSes (Windows....) won't produce a byte-for-byte copy of the data you write into the file.  You probably want to open the file in append binary mode `"ab"`.

Comment: "ab" has some slightly adverse behaviour (some merged files are not usable)

Comment: Please elaborate on "adverse behaviour". From your requirements "ab" looks perfectly right to me.

Comment: If you know the order of the files you need to concatenate, I'd try using `mmap()` and `memcpy()`to to solve this.

Comment: You use of `fread(&c, bytes, 1, read_from) == 1` is kind-of backwards. If can't be sure that there are `bytes` bytes in the file, you are better off doing:
` if ((readSize=fread(&c, 1, bytes, read_from)) != 0) fwrite(&c, 1, readSize, write_to);` you can even use `while` to loop through the file, though it is good to add some error handling for the `fwrite` as well.

Comment: `read` is a well known C library function.  It is a poor programming practice to use function names for variable names.  Suggest replacing `read` with something like: `bytesRead`

Comment: regarding: `if (!(read_from))
      return;`   This will create problems if your program has to be run more than once as the needed source files were removed via the call to `remove()`

Comment: regarding: ` if ((file_i + 1) == tasks) {
      while (fread(&c, 1, 1, read_from) == 1) {
        fwrite(&c, 1, 1, write_to);`  This only effects the transfer of the last file, not the prior files, so if the number bytes in the prior files is not an exact multiple of `bytes` then the resulting file will have gaps.